# defining escape character for a csv import

Tags: import, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a source file that has text columns which end with a "\" and I have specified "^" as the column delimiter.

I have the file format for this specified use - ESCAPE = 'NONE', but rows with "\^" are causing premature end-of-line errors - assuming SF is not interpreting the "\^" as a column delimiter - therefore the column count is off.

I have changed the file format to use something else for ESCAPE but get the same message. The offending rows have the right number of columns and a text column containing "\", that is not the last character in the column, imports correctly.

The values are exported from SQL Server.

Is this an escape character problem or am I overlooking something else? I am new to SF.

Comment: Hi David, can you provide a couple lines of sample data?

Comment: Multiple byte or multiple character delimiters are not yet supported in Snowflake. However, Snowflake has been working very hard to make this happen so we will hopefully see this released soon.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this same issue. Nomatter what I used as an escape character, when it showed up in my file next to a `"` at the end of a string it started causing trouble.

I switched my delimiter to `\u0001` which is a special "start of header" character that very rarely shows up, especially at the end of strings.

I wouldn't say this was an ideal option for us, but it worked and is something you might want to try.